# Refit Update package on Xamarin

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, refit

I've just updated a Xamarin solution  using the refit package (2.3.0. -> 2.4.1) and now the build is complaining:

```
RefitStubs.g.cs(37,27): error CS0102: The type `Sample.App.Api' already contains a definition for `Client'
    RefitStubs.cs(37,27): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
```

I've tried reverting the package version but same error occurs.  I've cleaned the solution but still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I've had related problems from the `*.g.cs` generated files... I do not know why the file is not overwritten sometimes during a (Re)Build All, but in other's projects that I've seen, make sure that you do **not** have a reference to the generated file itself within your project (.csproj) which sometimes happens when you are debugging into the `*.g.cs` file.

Also *Clean All* does not remove the Refit build task generated file `RefitStubs.g.cs` (or `RefitParams.rsp`) from the `obj` directory.

Try deleting the `obj` directory and perform a *(Re)Build All* again to see if that helps.

After (Re)Build All:

```
obj/ > ls -1
RefitParams.rsp
RefitStubs.g.cs
refit-test.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt
refit-test.exe
refit-test.exe.mdb
```

After Clean All:

```
obj/ > la -1
RefitParams.rsp
RefitStubs.g.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

Look if you have a refitStubs.cs file in your project root and remove it. Worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by resorting back to the previous version of Refit

Answer (score 0):

Like @cristianomad stated, this occurs due to the fact that **Refit** moved from using ***RefitStubs.cs*** which is public -to- ***RefitStubs.g.cs*** which is located in the ***/obj*** folder, therefore generating the same classes in the two files.

Simply remove the old ***RefitStubs.cs*** file and you´d be good to go.